# How to customize Toast background color when toast.view.background is null?

Tags: android, view, null, background, toast

Setting a color filter on the Toast's view's background seemed like the best approach. But `toast.view.background` is `null` so **I get an NPE** and the `setColorFilter()` method fails.

```
fun showToast(context: Context, text: String) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

    // customize background color
    toast.view.background.setColorFilter(
        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.toast_background),
        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
    )
    toast.show()
}
```

I also tried creating a custom drawable and setting `toast.view.background` to the drawable, but it shows my custom drawable **behind** the default Toast background.

```
view.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.toast_background)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom layout file and inflate from that. This will give you flexibility on setting background and adding more widgets to view. In following sample, I set background color to red and text color to white but you can customize according to your needs.

1. Create `toast_with_custom_view` layout file and add following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

2. Inflate custom view using following code:

```
private fun showToast() {
    // inflate the custom layout
    val toastView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_with_custom_view, null)
    toastView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = "Hello, world!"

    val toast = Toast(applicationContext)
    // set custom view
    toast.view = toastView
    toast.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should inflate your custom view and set it as toast view via `setView`. If your would able to customize background only it may lead to bugs. For example toast on some not popular smartphone models may be overriden with white themed toast (white background with black text on it). That's customizing the whole toast view is preferred way